# Go protoc compiler not adding package name to grpc.pb.go and pb.go

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, protoc, grpc-go

I'm trying to create my `grpc.pb.go` and `pb.go` files.

```
$ go version
go version go1.20.1 linux/amd64

$ protoc --version
libprotoc 3.21.12

$ uname -r
6.1.12-arch1-1-surface
```

Project root directory is: `/home/chris/go/src/projects/fabtest`

I have a `/proto` sub-directory for my `fabtest.proto` file. File begins:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package fabtest;
option go_package = ".";
```

From the sub-directory I run:

`proto/$ protoc -I=. --go_out=. ./fabtest.proto`

`proto/$ protoc -I=. --go-grpc_out=. ./fabtest.proto`

Using the RELATIVE PATH or the ABSOLUTE PATH has same result.

I get `package __` when `option go_package = ".";`

```
Code generated by protoc-gen-go-grpc. DO NOT EDIT.
versions:
protoc-gen-go-grpc v1.2.0
protoc             v3.21.12
source: fabtest.proto

package __

import (
context "context"
grpc "google.golang.org/grpc"
codes "google.golang.org/grpc/codes"
status "google.golang.org/grpc/status"
```

```
Code generated by protoc-gen-go. DO NOT EDIT.
versions:
protoc-gen-go v1.28.1
protoc        v3.21.12
source: fabtest.proto

package __

import (
protoreflect "google.golang.org/protobuf/reflect/protoreflect"
protoimpl "google.golang.org/protobuf/runtime/protoimpl"
reflect "reflect"
sync "sync"
```

I change `option go_package = "./fabtest";`

and I get the files with the correct `package fabtest` name but in the sub-sub-directory `fabtest/proto/fabtest`

If I run from the root project directory `/fabtest/`the result is the same as above.

The files compile but the compiler creates the directories according to the `option go_package`

How do I get `fabtest.grpc.pb.go` and `fabtest.pb.go` in the same directory as  `fabtest.proto`  *and* with the correct name `package fabtest` ?

WHAT I TRIED:

I changed the `option go_package = ...`  in the `.proto` file a number of times and also ran the compiler from the project root directory and the `/proto` sub-directory where my `fabtest.proto` file is.

I was expecting the two built files to have the package name `package fabtest` and in the `/proto` directory.

Comment: from https://protobuf.dev/reference/go/go-generated/ looks like you're missing the paths flag: `--go_opt=paths=source_relative ...`

Comment: yep that was it. I read so much on this but missed that one. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had to add below to `fabtest.proto`:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package fabtest;
option go_package = "/fabtest";
```

then run:

`$ protoc --proto_path=. --go_out=. --go_opt=paths=source_relative fabtest.proto`

and

`$ protoc --proto_path=. --go-grpc_out=. --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative fabtest.proto`